# Changing variable name from db to friendly format

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of items that a user selects from a dropdown and is saved to the db. The list of items are saved in an uppercase format. I'm looking to find an item from a db stream and return it in a 'friendly format'.

TS --

```
enumMap() {
  const oldValue = this.rows.map(item => item.oldValue);
  const savedItem = oldValue.find(element => element === 'SAVEDITEM');

  if (savedItem) {
    return 'Saved Item';
  }
}
```

HTML -

```
      <ngx-datatable-column name="Previously" prop="changedFrom" [minWidth]="50" [maxWidth]="150">
        <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
          <span> {{row.oldValue}} </span>
        </ng-template>
      </ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: What's the questions? What is a `friendly format`?

Comment: In the return field I'm looking to change 'SAVEDITEM' to 'Saved Item'.

Comment: You should look into [building a pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes-overview). This should help you transform your value to a more user friendly text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexes to do that along with a pipe.

But right now, you can't really.

`SAVEDITEM` has no delimitor and only a human (or a smart IA) would be able to do so.

Try saving it at least as `SAVED_ITEM` so that you know when to split it.

As for the pipe, the internal `titlecase` pipe should do the trick easily, no need to write a custom one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - titlecase works perfectly for single words, however if the result id 2 words, it doesn't work as I would like.